How kriging interpolation works in stratigraphy in EVS?
I am learning EVS kriging module and I am curious how kriging interpolation works in soil stratigraphy.
In its official help document, I found some infomation(at page 421) as follows:

Thus, it seems that the software just use consecutive integers to map the soil layers and then kriging it.
However, I am a little confused about this process.
For example, if the upper layer has value 1 and lower layer has value 3, by using kriging interpolation, is it possible that the software creates a layer (that actually does not exist) which has value 2 between the two existing layers?
From my perspective, there should be a best mapping rule between the soil layers and the integers. Just mapping the two things randomly does not make sense.

I misunderstood it. Actually it just uses Z coordinate to make the kriging interpolation.
